# Can “in alpha” be used as an antonym to “in beta,” or it’s a totally different animal?

Tags: etymology, idioms, word-usage

I was drown to the phrase, “in beta” in the following passage of New York Times’  (June 16) publicity of their own new scheme, Trending:

> “The Times unveils a new tool, Trending, that shows you what Times
>   stories are most popular with readers at a given instant. Trending
>   also lets you know what stories are most popular on Facebook, Twitter
>   and Google, and shows you which stories were most popular last week. 
>   Don’t want to be the last to know? Check out Trending. Brand new. **Now
>   in beta (testing mode).** The Times has a sizable readership, but you
>   haven’t been able to feel that presence when you are on the site. Now
>   you can. (We still have a ways to go — **we’re in beta, after all** — but
>   this is a start).
>   http://www.nytimes.com/times-insider/2015/06/16/trending/?

online slang dictionary defines “in beta” as “a pre-release product that is released for testing.” It doesn't specify “in beta” as an internet or computor terminology.

Google Ngram shows the emergence of the usage of both “in beta” and “in alpha” in mid 1900s.

Why did “in beta” come to be used in the sense of “testing mode,” though it sounds like as if a disclaimer?

Can we use “in beta” in the sense of "in test, in development, in preparation" of a product/ service  or scheme / plan other than Internet associated context?

Can “in alpha” be used as an antonym, or contrast word to “in beta,” or it’s a totally different animal?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the origin of "beta" to describe a "user-testing" phase of computer development?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/40013/whats-the-origin-of-beta-to-describe-a-user-testing-phase-of-computer-devel)

Comment: It's not 100% clear from your question whether you're aware, but "alpha" is not really an antonym of "beta". The alpha stage is actually the one *before* the beta stage. Before you get as far as beta, you have alpha. "In alpha" can be used just like "in beta"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Alpha testing* is testing you do in-house, when you *know* there are still problems, and the product might not even be finished. *Beta testing* is when you enlist friendly users to test a product that passed all your internal tests, but you know there are probably issues due to the incredible creativity of the end-user, and the endless variety of user environments. The opposite of *in beta* would be *released* -- or perhaps *final* or *finished* or *production-quality.*

Comment: "Gold" was once common for the final or released version, probably from the the use of gold master CDs though perhaps also referencing the gold record presses from the music industry.